# Fungus gnats Trap made at Home

Tags: pests

We have a fungus gnat infestation at home, due to overwatering one of the plants. I wanted to make a trap so first tried leaving a bowl of red wine vinegar outside. Unfortunately it didn't catch anything. Then (after doing some research online) decided to do a mixture of red wine vinegar, water, and soap and results were much better. I'm gonna try one more trap and was wondering:

1. What role does soap and water play so that the mixture is more effective in trapping these insects?
2. What is the optimal mixture that one can create? (i.e., how much water, how much soap, and how much vinegar)

Comment: I just ignore the ones on my seedlings - they disappear once I plant them outside. If you have an infestation in houseplants, then the soilless mix in one of the pots doesn't drain well/is overwatered. Fungus gnats live in wet soil, so if your houseplant has them, repot ir and/or let it thoroughly dry out between waterings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What role does soap and water play so that the mixture is more
> effective in trapping these insects?

The trap works by attracting the gnats with vinegar, and drowning them.  Gnats normally don't drown because surface tension prevents them from entering the liquid- they are too small to push through.  This is common at insect-sizes.

[image: A winged insect on water, supported by surface tension, with the depressions its legs make in the water visible in the shadow cast on the bottom of the pool]

[image: A small ant leans against a droplet of water without entering it]

The soap you added is a surfactant, which means it reduces the surface tension.  Things that were held up on the surface will now push right through and drown.

[image: An ant entirely encapsulated in a water droplet on a leaf]

> What is the optimal mixture that one can create? (i.e., how much
> water, how much soap, and how much vinegar)

As far as I know, the water doesn't contribute to the situation.  The vinegar attracts them and the soap makes them drown.  I use these traps frequently and I use vinegar with a drop of dish soap, it doesn't take much soap.

I have found that something with steep sides, like a mug, drowns them much better than something with a gentle shore like a saucer.  I have also found they prefer some vinegars to others, but any vinegar seems to work.

Answer (score 4):

To my surprise I found that fungus gnats can be controlled by applying ground cinnamon to the surface of the problem plant.

Sticky strips also work to reduce numbers and keeping the plant drier is very effective.